# How to handle slider with hidden check box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, watir

I want to handle slider with hidden check box for scripts using watir.
Can any one help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: You'll need to provide the specific slider control you're working with. Different slider controls will require different Watir code.

Comment: Just assume whether someone can answer your question for your given detail before you ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

This would be more like visibility: hidden

Try setting the checkbox's opacity to 0. If you want the checkbox to be out of flow try position:absolute and offset the checkbox by a large number.

HTML

```
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="valueofcheckbox" checked="checked" style="opacity:0; position:absolute; left:9999px;">Option Text</label>
```

How many checkboxes do you have at this page? If there is only one then this might work:

```
browser.checkbox(attribute: attribute-value).when_present.set
```

Comment: only one checkbox this is our code                                                                                           <div class="slider round"></div><input name="driver[status]" value="0" type="hidden"><input data-on-text="Yes" data-off-text="No" id="togBtn" value="1" checked="checked" name="driver[status]" type="checkbox">